# Neo4j: Unsupported administration command: CREATE DATABASE demo

Tags: neo4j, bigdata

I want create new database 'demo' in neo4j, but I see a bug:

[image]

I was search but can't find result, can you help me? Thank all!

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? Did you switch to the system database first?

Comment: i use Neo4j version 4.0, and i was switch to the system database, but it fail.

Comment: Are you using Neo4j Enterprise Edition? Multi-tenancy (multi DB) is an EE feature.

Comment: i install via guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-neo4j-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: As noted by Tomaz, this is installing a Community Edition, you won't have access to multi-database this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the URL you used to install Neo4j, there is a remark about the community version of Neo4j and how it doesn't support multiple databases.

> Note: The Community Edition of Neo4j supports running a single
> database at a time. Additionally, the Community version does not
> include the capability to assign roles and permissions to users so
> those steps are not included in this tutorial. For more information
> about various features that are supported by the Community Edition of
> Neo4j, consult the Neo4j Documentation here.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the neo4j.conf file and uncomment this line

dbms.default_database=neo4j

Change the neo4j  to whatever database name you want for a new database.
*Note: names must have between 3 and 63 characters.

For example:   dbms.default_database=mydatabase*

after that add a new database name. then we can maintain new DB but we can't switch to old one, if we need to do that we have to comment above mentioned line again